# Would these lines of code affect each other?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am listening/watching the tutorial on Paul Hegarty from the App Store. In his lesson he states that you should ALWAYS synthesize your properties on the implementation file like so:

```
@sysnthesize example = _example;
```

I am also doing a apple documentation tutorial that does not synthesize properties. It also has init methods like so:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _name = name;

        _location = location;

        _date = date;

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Will these to interact, cancel or otherwise mess with each other if add them together like so:

```
@implementation BirdSighting

@synthesize name = _name;

@synthesize location = _location;

@synthesize date = _date;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _name = name;

        _location = location;

        _date = date;

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking of it in terms of "will these interact" is perhaps not the right mental model. The place to start is *understanding what each of those lines does*. So let's consider one from each example:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

If a property (@property, usually in the .h) called name exists, then this does a few things:

1. It creates two methods, called -setName: and -name, which set and get the instance variable _name
2. If an instance variable called _name doesn't exist, it creates one

Now the other example:

```
_name = name;
```

This does one thing; it assigns the address of 'name' to the instance variable _name.

So now that we understand what those do, let's consider how they interact:

1. If there's no explicit instance variable called _name to assign to, then the second line will not compile. The first line is *one way* to make sure there is an instance variable of that name
2. If you set the name property (either via dot notation or the -setName methods, it makes no difference), then that will modify the same _name instance variable, by means of the methods created by the @synthesize statement
3. If you use _name in your code, or if you use dot notation or the -name method, it will have the value most recently assigned to it by either of these means.
4. Doing _name = name rather than self.name = name; will NOT call the -setName: method, which means anything it does besides set (for example: retaining the argument) will not happen.

One additional consideration:
In very recent versions of Xcode, the compiler will automatically put the @synthesize statement in for you if you leave it out. This is a good thing (less typing, less redundancy, less things to get wrong), but it could be confusing if you're not expecting it. For example, my point 1 above will not apply with new versions.